# YouTube API PHP Disable Chat

Tags: youtube-api, chat, youtube-data-api

I want to create a live streams from the API, and I can do it, but I want to disable the chat.

Is it possible to disable the chat when I create the liveStream or the Broadcast? If it is possible, can you tell me the name of the function to do this?

Comment: youtube api sucks for tihs. i heard they can't let you interact with live chat or enabled comments via api currently, which is pretty terrible imo.